# Can't attach tooltip to fullcalendar eventAfterRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am new at js and I am trying to show full title of event in tooltip. But nothing happened. What can be the problem?

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterRender: function (event, element) {
        var tooltip = event.title;
        $(element).attr("fc-title", tooltip)
        $(element).tooltip({ container:"body" })
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to set `title` property `$(element).prop('title', tooltip)`

Comment: You mean, like this? $(element).attr('fc-title', tooltip)
            $(element).prop('fc-title', tooltip)

Comment: `$(element).prop('title', tooltip)`